# What is the significance of the word "cuss" in Fantastic Mr. Fox?

Tags: plot-explanation, fantastic-mr-fox

This word is used so much in the movie [*Fantastic Mr. Fox*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Mr._Fox_(film)).

What is the significance of word "cuss"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you can't really put the F word in a kids movie. That's why they just used *cuss*.

By using "Cuss", they did a nice job of turning the phrase, thus allowing both adults and children to watch the movie and extrapolate their own meaning of this word. Or more, getting amused by following conversation.

> **Mr Fox:** I understand what you're saying, and your comments are valuable, but I'm gonna ignore your advice.
>
> **Badger:** The cuss you are.
>
> **Mr Fox:** The cuss am I? Are you cussing with me?
>
> **Badger:** No, you cussing with me?
>
> **Mr Fox:** Don't cussing point at me!
>
> **Badger:** If you're gonna cuss with somebody, you're not gonna cuss with me, you little cuss!
>
> **Mr Fox:** You're not gonna cuss with me!

Also note that *cuss* is another form of *curse* which is a, kinda offensive, word for expressing anger or annoyance. (Credits to @AndrewThompson)

Comment: It might pay to also point out that 'cuss' is a slang form of 'curse' which means, among other things, 'an offensive word or phrase used to express anger or annoyance'.